# Running a 7 pin OLED with 4 pins (I2C)

Tags: i2c, library, pins, display

I have an OLED with this 7 pin pinout:

[image: My OLED]

I want to use an existing code i found that makes use of U8Glib.
But in the example, use uses 4 pins to control the OLED via I2C.
This is the pinout he uses:

[image: Pinout]

Is it possible to control my OLED via 4 pins and use U8Glib to simplify my project by making use of the example code i found?

EDIT: Here is also a picture of the back of the OLED PCB that mentions how to use IIC but i do not understand it!
[image: back of pcb]

Comment: That looks like it may be an SPI interface, not I2C, so no. You can't.

Comment: Unless of course U8Glib has an SPI example for that board. I assume it's an SSD1306? Most small OLEDs are...

Comment: Looks configurable to I2C / 3-wire SPI / 4-wire SPI depending on the presence / absence of R1-R4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.rhydolabz.com/displays-c-88/096-oled-display-module-spii2c-128x64-7-pin-blue-p-2079.html) has the answer to your questions. For reference:

> Setting up SPI/I2C Connection with GMS096A OLED Module
>
> Being a new entry to the market, only limited resources are available
>   on this small piece of miracle (GMS096A). I2C/SPI configuration always
>   demands helpful resources as in any case. For the SPI setup, the
>   module comes in 4 wire SPI configuration by default and to make it
>   work with the arduinos you can use these libraries from Adafruit.
>
> For the I2C setup it demands a little bit of work on the module.
>   Actually it was one of our customers who shared these simple
>   configuration steps with us, start with resoldering the resistor from
>   position R3 to R1 and then short the R8 resistor with some solder tin
>   (0 Ohm resistor). The R6 and R7 pullup resistors are already soldered,
>   nothing to do there. Once done, the module is ready for I2C
>   communication! The CS Pin is not necessarily needed, so just connect
>   it to GND. The DC Pin selects the address. For standard address wire
>   it to GND. The RES-pin needs a low pulse at startup and high voltage
>   during operation (as in SPI mode), a 100nF capacitor to GND and a 10k
>   res to VCC would be ideal!

Your module might differ sightly. But you should be able to figure it out from there. The pulse on the RES-pin needed at startup took me a while to figure out!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works IIC as described above, with my Arduino MEGA.
You can also connect RST Pin at Arduino RESET signal, so no need of extra R and C components

Answer (score 1):

That is a SPI interface. Often the CS is missing, but you seem to have that pin. I suggest to start with the software PCI mode of the U8Glib.

This is the best explanation that I can find: [Github: SSD1306 based OLED connected to Arduino](https://github.com/jandelgado/arduino/wiki/SSD1306-based-OLED-connected-to-Arduino)

Would you consider using the newer [U8g2 library](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2) ?
It is easier to use with Arduino boards that have more memory. But it has also the same mode for low memory usage, just like the U8Glib.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to control my OLED via 4 pins and use U8Glib to simplify my project by making use of the example code i found?

i'm sure somewhere there is an i2c->spi bridge. if not, you can always code your arduino to behave like one.

short of that, you can simply code to control the board via spi.